# Solving quantum harmonic oscillator in 1D for a displacement of the ground state as initial state [NDSolve]

Tags: differential-equations

As an exercise, I want to numerically solve the quantum harmonic oscillator in 1D.

```
xmax = 5; tmax = 10;
schrodingerEq = -(1/2) D[ψ[x, t], {x, 2}] + (1/2) x^2 ψ[x, t] == ID[ψ[x, t], t]
ψinit[x_] := (1/π)^(1/4) Exp[-1/2 (x - 1)^2]
sol = NDSolve[{schrodingerEq, ψ[x, 0] == ψinit[x]}, ψ, {x, -xmax, xmax}, {t, 0, tmax}]
```

But I get the following errors

```
NDSolve::bcart: Warning: an insufficient number of boundary conditions have been specified for the direction of independent variable x. Artificial boundary effects may be present in the solution. >>

NDSolve::eerr: Warning: scaled local spatial error estimate of 165.59557034256125` at t = 10.` in the direction of independent variable x is much greater than the prescribed error tolerance. Grid spacing with 37 points may be too large to achieve the desired accuracy or precision. A singularity may have formed or a smaller grid spacing can be specified using the MaxStepSize or MinPoints method options. >>
```

Obviously I need a second boundary condition, because I'm solving a second order differential equation. I'm not sure where to put a logical constraint on the derivative of $\psi$ here.

Comment: Looks to me like you need *two* boundary conditions, because you've only specified an *initial* condition. The wave function should go to zero at $\pm\infty$, and to implement that, you might just force the function to be zero 'far enough' away.

Comment: Add the boundary conditions `\[Psi][xmax, t] == 0` and `\[Psi][-xmax, t] == 0` and change `xmax` to 6.

Comment: Also, `ID[ψ[x, t], t]` should be `I D[ψ[x, t], t]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, putting it together from the comments:

```
xmax=6;tmax=30;
schrodingerEq=-(1/2) D[ψ[x,t],{x,2}]+(1/2) x^2 ψ[x,t]==I D[ψ[x,t],t];
ψinit[x_]:=(1/π)^(1/4) Exp[-1/2 (x-1)^2];
sol=NDSolve[{schrodingerEq,ψ[x,0]==\[Psi]init[x],ψ[xmax,t]==0,ψ[-xmax,t]==0},
    ψ,{x,-xmax,xmax},{t,0,tmax}];
solution=ψ/. sol[[1]];
Manipulate[Plot[Abs[solution[x,t]],{x,-xmax,xmax},PlotRange->{0,.8}],{t,0,tmax}]
```

[image]